# Why does sympy.diff not differentiate sympy polynomials as expected?

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials

I am trying to figure out why `sympy.diff` does not differentiate `sympy` polynomials as expected. Normally, `sympy.diff` works just fine if a symbolic variable is defined and the polynomial is NOT defined using `sympy.Poly`.  However, if the function is defined using `sympy.Poly`, `sympy.diff` does not seem to actually compute the derivative.  Below is a code sample that shows what I mean:

```
import sympy as sy

# define symbolic variables
x = sy.Symbol('x')
y = sy.Symbol('y')

# define function WITHOUT using sy.Poly
f1 = x + 1
# define function WITH using sy.Poly
f2 = sy.Poly(x + 1, x, domain='QQ')

# compute derivatives and return results
df1 = sy.diff(f1,x)
df2 = sy.diff(f2,x)
print('f1:  ',f1)
print('f2:  ',f2)
print('df1:  ',df1)
print('df2:  ',df2)
```

This prints the following results:

```
f1:   x + 1
f2:   Poly(x + 1, x, domain='QQ')
df1:   1
df2:   Derivative(Poly(x + 1, x, domain='QQ'), x)
```

Why does `sympy.diff` not know how to differentiate the `sympy.Poly` version of the polynomial?  Is there a way to differentiate the `sympy` polynomial, or a way to convert the `sympy` polynomial to the form that allows it to be differentiated?

**Note**: I tried with different domains (i.e., `domain='RR'` instead of `domain='QQ'`), and the output does not change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug.  You can get around it by calling `diff` directly on the `Poly` instance.  Ideally calling the function `diff` from the top level sympy module should yield the same result as calling the method `diff`.

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: from sympy.abc import x

In [3]: p = Poly(x+1, x, domain='QQ')

In [4]: p.diff(x)
Out[4]: Poly(1, x, domain='QQ')

In [5]: diff(p, x)
Out[5]: Derivative(Poly(x + 1, x, domain='QQ'), x)

In [6]: diff(p, x).doit()
Out[6]: Derivative(Poly(x + 1, x, domain='ZZ'), x)
```

Comment: This has now been fixed in the master branch with https://github.com/sympy/sympy/commit/4d30e847d2f53f7015cf37e170b8f9f1fa3fc4ce